# Get html node on href click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

In my html page I want to get html node on its href click.

example:

**HTML FILE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/" data-type="W3">Click1</a></p>
<p><a href="https://www.google.com/html/" data-type="google">Click2</a></p>


</body>
</html>
```

When `Click1` is clicked I want to value: `W3`
When `Click2` is clicked I want to value: `google`

Currently, I am using `document.documentElement.outerHTML` to get complete html string and parse it. Is there a better way to get `data-type` value on a href click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(){ console.log( $(this).data('type') ) })
```

JavaScript:

```
var link = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
  link[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log(this.dataset.type)
  });
}
```